# The differential is NOT the Jacobi Matrix?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, definition, self-learning

In the book Analysis II by *C.T. Michaels* the *differential* is introduced as the Jacobi-Matrix. In class we had the following definition:

> **Definition**: Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ be open, $f: U \to \mathbb{R}^n$, $x_0 \in U$
>
> $f$ is at $x_0$ differentiable $ \iff \exists A: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $ \displaystyle \lim_{x \to x_0}_{x \neq 0} \displaystyle \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)-A(x-x_0)}{||x-x_0||}=0$
>
> **Note**: We call $A \in \hom(\mathbb{R}^m, \mathbb{R}^n)$ the differential of $f$ at point $x_0$ and we also write $A=df(x_0)$

My tutor said there are many books where the Jacobi-Matrix and the differential are said to be equal, but he mentioned they really are not.

Oddly enough when I returned home after this Colloquium in Mathematics I did try to get some practice and just found the definition of the differential being equal to the Jacobi-Matrix as in C.T. Michaels.

Now consider the following exercise (found in a paper by Salamon)

> **Exercise**: Show that $f$ is differentiable and compute the differential $df$ for all points in the domain: $$ f: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2, \ f(x)= (ye^{ix}, xe^{iy}) $$

**My approach**: Showing that $f$ is differentiable is easy, I compute the Jacobi Matrix $$J_f= \begin{pmatrix}iye^{ix} \\ e^{iy} \end{pmatrix} \in \text{Mat}_{2,2}( \mathbb{C})  $$
And see that all the partial derivatives exists and are continuous $ \implies f$ is differentiable.

**Questions**:

- How do I find the differential? If I plugin the Jacobi-Matrix into the definition above I can't seem to come up with the correct result
- Is it wrong to treat the Jacobi-Matrix and the differential as equal? (considering the definition as given in my class of course)

Comment: As a side note, the concept of total derivatives is an intrinsic one, which means that it is coordinate-free. It is not general enough (and hence not satisfactory enough) to simply use the Jacobi matrix to define the differentiability, though which is a computationally convenient device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between a linear map and a matrix, since a linear map is defined independently of a basis. In the definition you quote, the differential $A$ is a linear map. The Jacobi-matrix represents this map according to the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, you're a right indeed, that is a subtle but valid point. Any hints on how to compute the differential?

Comment: @Spaced The approach you used is correct, since the partial derivatives are continuous. The Jacobian describes a linear map, which does the job.

Comment: @Spaced Actually, now that I look more closely, your function is a bit strange. Is the range $\mathbb{R}^2$ of $\mathbb{C}^2$?

Comment: I thought that myself, it might be a misprint, however I did copy the problem correctly

Comment: @Spaced Very strange, seems to me it should be $\mathbb{C}^2$. Can't really help you with that unfortunately, I don't know a lot about complex differentiability.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is a misprint then @VincentBoelens because I have not dealt with complex differentiability yet myself, this is just my second week in multivariable calculus.